# Where do I find android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$attr?

Tags: android, adt, android-support-library, google-cast

### Short version

I'm getting an unhandled exception when instantiating an android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton object. I get:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$attr
```

Where is this class? Or if it's auto-generated, how do I get it to auto-generate?

### Longer version

I am following along with the tutorial for Android app development for chromecast found here: https://developers.google.com/cast/cast_2nd-screen_app_tutorial

I am developing using the ADT bundled eclipse, on ubuntu 13.04.

I imported the following jar files into a libs directory right in my workspace and have included them in my Java Build Path via "Add Jars..." button in the "Libraries" tab of the "Java Build Path" panel of my project's properties:

- GoogleCastSdkAndroid-1.0.0.jar
- android-support-v4.jar
- android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
- android-support-v7-gridlayout.jar
- android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar

I have a single activity (the default "hello world" created by Eclipse), and have not modified the layout. The only code I need to add to cause the error (pasted below) to show is this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton;
...
MediaRouteButton mrb = new MediaRouteButton(this.getApplicationContext());
```

When I build and run the app I see the error message pasted below in LogCat (I can post more of it if anyone feels it's relevant). The key things I notice are that I seem to be missing android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$attr (NoClassDefFoundError), and that it is being called from android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton's constructor

```
08-12 00:36:02.837: E/AndroidRuntime(29600): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$attr
08-12 00:36:02.837: E/AndroidRuntime(29600):    at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:117)
08-12 00:36:02.837: E/AndroidRuntime(29600):    at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:113)
08-12 00:36:02.837: E/AndroidRuntime(29600):    at com.jeffbmartinez.helicast.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
...
```

The fact that it is running the MediaRouteButton's constructor leads me to believe the jar files are being properly found so I don't think I misconfigured eclipse in relation to the dependencies (jar files). However, my understanding is that these 'R' files are auto-generated. If this is correct, where is my android.support.v7.mediarouter.R file? I do not see it in the gen directory, which where com.jeffbmartinez.helicast.R file is being placed.

Furthermore, I find it curious that the MediaRouteButton refers to a package name that I cannot find in any of the 5 jar dependencies listed above. android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar contains only **android.support.v7.app.*** and **android.support.v7.media.***.

The only place I find reference to **android.support.v7.mediarouter**, aside from my error logs, is at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/mediarouter/package-summary.html but there is little information there.

Am I missing a dependency? If so, where do I get it or how do I generate it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't just include the jars. You need to add the `android.support.v7.mediarouter` project as a Android Library dependency. That way, the resources from the project will get merged into your own.

Inside the `mediarouter` folder run `android update lib-project -p .` and then you can add it as a dependency.

Comment: Pulling it in as a library with resources did the trick. Didn't realize that was an option. Made it a lot easier to google with that idea in mind. For future visitors: To do it with eclipse rather than command line, follow this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Comment: I followed the steps and imported android-support-v7-mediarouter project. I getting an error that says: 
     error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'. styles.xml /android-support-v7-mediarouter/res/values

Cannot seem to find a solution to resolve this. W/o this resolved I couldn't get my application project to run. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @bond..Hi, i am facing the same issue..could you tell me the solution if you have found one..it would be really helpful..

Comment: It was an issue of how I was importing the support library. Once I removed and re-imported the support library and did a clean, it finally worked. Hope this helps

Comment: I used Android libraries importing from the beginning, using this: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender , yet I have the same error... how come?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid any XML compilation errors just configure the build path to resolve to ANDROID API 17 (e.g Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse )