# customizing using Appcompat not works

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I have used Appcompat for Actionbar to get actionbar in Android 2.1 devices. I included appcompat library. but it shows Theme.AppCompat.Light not found. please provide suggestions.![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below Step: 
1) File->Import (`android-sdk-xxx\extras\android\support\v7`). Choose `appcompat`
2) `Project-> properties->Android`. In the section library `Add` and choose `appCompat`

Comment: :it works.but Action bar displays only in gray & back themes only. my customized actionbar[downloaded from http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ theme not works

Comment: if i change it to HOLO theme & sdk min version to 11, then the theme i downloaded works well. but i need same theme for SDK-minversion 7.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182535/where-do-i-find-android-support-v7-mediarouter-rattr/18182710#18182710), you can't just add the `jar` files, you need to add the full project as a Library dependency. You can find the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res).

Comment: i'm using fedora..how do i run this command **android update lib-project -p**

Comment: I've linked to the official instructions in my answer, they're better as it's all in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. it was useful.I tried it. but also displays same error in styles